# Brainfuck - почему программа +[+] не цикл в отличии от +[]?

Tags: brainfuck

Спасибо.

Comment: Возможно Вы хотели спросить, почему `+[+]` не бесконечный цикл в отличи от `+[]`?

Comment: Ага. Может быть цикл прерывается потому что значение ячейки увеличивается до какого-то значения, а потом становится равным нулю?

Comment: О, наконец-то вопрос не по php :-P

Comment: @VladD, и не говори...

Answer (score 2):

Итак, что бы понять, почему одно работает так, а другое иначе, переведем это в более понятную форму.

```
+[+]

++(*p);
while (*p) {
    ++(*p);
}
```

второй вариант преобразовывается в

```
++(*p);
while (*p) {
}
```

Из этого уже видно, что первый код будет продвигаться до первого нулевого символа и потом остановится. А вот второй - как повезет. Если ноль, то хорошо, а иначе - зацикливаемся - условие то не изменяется.

Comment: Мне кажется, что в первом примере кода изменяется не `p`, а `*p`, верно? Или в BF тоже есть integer overflow?

Comment: А, да, по модулю 256, точно.

Comment: ох да, значение. Но думаю, тут переполнение сработает.

Comment: Отладчик говорит про переполнение. http://www.iamcal.com/misc/bf_debug/